# switching views with TabBarController shifts the view's content down

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

An issue with iOS7 I am having in an app of mine is that whenever I switch views using a UITabBarController the contents of some(but not all) the views get shifted around.  One has its contents scroll downward every time the view comes back on the screen until eventually everything is shoved below the lenght of the phone.

The weird part is that Ive checked the frames of the ViewController's view and the labels/buttons inside the view inside viewWillAppear and none of the values change.  Yet the content always shifts down.

This is a new issue added in through iOS7 and I'm at a loss as to what could be the problem.  My best guess is its something to do with the AutoLayout but removing it seems to have no effect.

Has anyone else run in to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when using autolayout.  In your storyboard for the view controller, go to the attributes inspector and make sure that extend edges under top bars and/or extend edges under bottom bars is not checked.  When those are checked, some of the content may be hidden underneath your top or bottom bars.

[image]

Comment: Isn't this an Xcode 5 feature that's to be used with the iOS 7 SDK? Since that's under NDA and not released yet, I would think this isn't an answer to his question.